# loop through one list and show results for closest match for each element in another list

Tags: python

How do I loop through one list and show results for closest match for each element in another text. Currently there are two lists:

```
Items_1 = ['Apple', 'Red Apple', 'Green Apple', 'Orange 1ltr', 'Orange 5ml', 'Grapes', 'Grapes 500ml', 'Grapes 1lt']
Items_2 = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Grapes']
```

Currently I can get results for one word

```
difflib.get_close_matches('Apple', Items_1)
['Apple', 'Red Apple', 'Green Apple']
```

I tried the below code but does not seem to work

```
for i in Items_2
    print(difflib.get_close_matches(Item_1[i], Items_2))
```

I would like for each word in Items_2 show results such as below

```
Item_2   Item_1
Apple    'Apple', 'Red Apple', 'Green Apple'
Orange   'Orange 1ltr', 'Orange 5ml'
Grapes   'Grapes', 'Grapes 500ml', 'Grapes 1lt'
```

Comment: replace `difflib.get_close_matches(Item_1[i], Items_2)` by `difflib.get_close_matches(i, Items_1)`

Comment: @keepAlive I get an error showing: invalid syntax when i replace with your solution

Comment: @Gune you need suggestions from Item_1 list for each word in Item_2, am I right?

Comment: It works now. I had made an error in the code. Final code should be as follows.... for i in Items_2:
    print(difflib.get_close_matches(i, Items_1))

Comment: So! Was my suggestion the problem? *No*. It was the solution. The error you had has nothing to do with my suggestion. Indeed, ***[colons in python blocks are necessary](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/341041/255630)***.

Comment: Also, if any answer does what you want, tell it to the community by ticking it as correct. I mean, you have been happy that we took time to help you. Let's ensure that other people can also benefit from the time spent here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import difflib

Items_1 = ['Apple', 'Red Apple', 'Green Apple', 'Orange 1ltr', 'Orange 5ml', 'Grapes', 'Grapes 500ml', 'Grapes 1lt']
Items_2 = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Grapes']

print("%-8s %s" % ("Items_2", "Items_1"))
for item in Items_2:
    print("%-8s %s" % (item, ", ".join("'%s'" % x for x in difflib.get_close_matches(item, Items_1))))
```

Output:

```
Items_2   Items_1
Apple    'Apple', 'Red Apple', 'Green Apple'
Orange   'Orange 5ml', 'Orange 1ltr'
Grapes   'Grapes', 'Grapes 1lt', 'Grapes 500ml'
```

Comment: thanks for the answer this works well. However could this be saved as a pandas data frame. where the item_1 output will be in 3 columns since its 3 matches and Item_2 will be in one column

Answer (score 0):

If you want it printed nicely you can use PrettyTable:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

pt = PrettyTable()
pt.field_names = ['Item_2', 'Item_1']
for item in Items_2:
    pt.add_row([item, close_match(item, Items_1)])
```

Where `close_match` could be the matching function you used (`difflib.get_close_matches`) or any other.

Output of `print(pt)`:

```
+--------+------------------------------------------+
| Item_2 |                  Item_1                  |
+--------+------------------------------------------+
| Apple  |  ['Apple', 'Red Apple', 'Green Apple']   |
| Orange |      ['Orange 1ltr', 'Orange 5ml']       |
| Grapes | ['Grapes', 'Grapes 500ml', 'Grapes 1lt'] |
+--------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Also note that variable names usually start with lower case letters so you should consider changing that in your code.

Comment: thanks for the answer this works well. However could this be saved as a pandas data frame. where the item_1 output will be in 3 columns since its 3 matches and Item_2 will be in one column